# How to inject the GraphServiceClient in Asp.net 6 (with application permissions NOT delegation permissions)

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I have managed to get the GraphServiceClient to work on its own in daemon code, but would like to be able to inject it into my razor pages' constructor as well.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2022-08-02T16:22:00"),
                new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2022-08-02T23:59:00")
            };

var res = await _graphServiceClient.Users["smtp>"]
    .CalendarView
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Select("start,end,subject")
    .GetAsync();
```

What code should be add to the builder?

The Id's and Secrets being read are valid and correct.

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "client.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "tenantid",
    "ClientId": "clientid",
    "ClientSecret": "clientsecret"
  },

  "Graph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  },
```

I have tried the following and received: ***MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call*** even though it exposes an injectable GraphServiceClient to my page.

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was trying to call GetAccessTokenForUserAsync (on ITokenAcquisition) at the Api Controller (Asp.net core 6.0).

"Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call."

I was able to resolve it by using AuthorizeForScopes attribute on controller action. Example -
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { AppConstants.ApiAppScope })]

Where AppConstants.ApiAppScope is the scope of my own WebApi.
If you are calling Graph api, it would be - https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

if you are calling your own Azure AD Web api, it would be something like api://app-id-of-web-api-as-registered-in-Azure-Ad/scope-defined-under-expose-as-api (i.e. api://ff1acf30-8c34-45ce-9bf6-7a47fa42d6be/access_as_user)

I couldn't figure out how to use built-in InMemory cache and I ended up creating my own caching. Caching is needed because call to GetAccessTokenForUserAsync will prompt the user to login again (if the scope is new).

This is my own application (self-disclaimer) that I am using for research (working sample)- https://securityresearchlab.aspnet4you.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is actually built into the graph services client already (as of 1.2.0), although it wasn't very easy to find and doesn't seem to be included in their core documentation for the client (that I can find at this time).

[AzureAD GraphServiceClient using app permissions](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/1.2.0#you-can-now-specify-scopes-and-app-permissions-for-graphserviceclient)

Leaving everything else the same, you should be able to simply change your call to include the WithAppOnly extension:

```
var res = await _graphServiceClient.Users["smtp>"]
    .CalendarView
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .WithAppOnly()
    .Select("start,end,subject")
    .GetAsync();
```